# Pass multiple id(s) in query string and get data for them in mysql in node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a get API in nodejs , which gets string of variables as query string ( delimited by ",") as follows

```
const mac = req.query.mac; 
console.log(mac); // 00:11:22:33:FF:EE,11:11:22:33:FF:EE
var sql =  mysql.format("SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE macId IN ?",[mac]);
        connection.query(sql, function(err, row) ...{ ... .. }
```

But i am getting errors

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''00:11:22:33:FF:EE,11:11:22:33:FF:EE'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE macId IN '00:11:22:33:FF:EE,11:11:22:33:FF:EE'"
}
```

**Someone please help !!**

Comment: `''00:11:22:33:FF:EE,11:11:22:33:FF:EE''` additional quote is getting added

Comment: But i haven't added nay extra , how can handle this ?

Comment: `mysql.escape()` try with this ?

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''\\'00:11:22:33:FF:EE,11:11:22:33:FF:EE\\''' at line 1",

Comment: Above result after using mysql.escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mistake is in converting mac from string to array

```
[mac]
```

won't convert it to a string. try this instead:

```
const mac = req.query.mac; 
const macArr = mac.split(',');
var sql =  mysql.format("SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE macId IN (?)", macArr);
connection.query(sql, function(err, row) ...{ ... .. }
```

Comment: STILL AS THIS  ------------------------------------------------------------- code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''00:11:22:33:FF:EE'' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "SELECT * FROM user_email WHERE macId IN '00:11:22:33:FF:EE'"
}

Comment: Only one mac is passed to query now

Comment: Its solved now, used brackets on ? as this (?) solved the issue

Comment: oh sure my mistake, I will edit my answer. thanks for sharing